Blender - Sketchfab multiple armatures
The problem is that in my scene I have a hoverbike, using its own skeleton - it floats above the ground. And the second character is a girl sitting on it. She's animated too. When I export the scene to Sketchfab - it shows only one of them animated at a time, allowing to pick a different animation via a dropdown menu. But I want them animated at the same time. I tried NLA strips - the same thing - it binds the NLA strip or an action to an Armature - and still plays only one at a time. Maybe you know how to get them to play in Sketchfab simultaneously?
Thanks

In case there's someone facing the same problem, there's an answer. No, it's not possible at all. Because of the way the engines like Sketchfab and Marmoset are working. In other words - it needs to be a single armature with as many bones and hierarchies in it as you want, but only one root. So merge everything into one root and one armature - then it will work.
